# Distance between centroid and incenter in a right-angled isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let ABC be a right-angled isosceles triangle where AB = BC = a. Assume that C is its centroid and I is its incenter. Find, in terms of a, the distance between C and I.

Answer : $CI= \frac{{a \cdot (3\sqrt{2}-4})}{12}$

How to find it ?

Comment: You began by designating the point C to be one of the vertices of triangle ABC, so you are not free to label the centroid as C. There are plenty more letters of the alphabet. Use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Coordinate Geometry is allowed, WLOG we can assume $\displaystyle B(0,0),A(a,0), C(0,a)$

So, the equation of $AC$ will be $\displaystyle\frac xa+\frac ya=1\iff x+y-a=0$

So, the centroid will be $\displaystyle C\left(\frac a3,\frac a3\right)$

Now, if $I(p,q)$  then we have the perpendicular distance of $I$ from $AB,BC,CA$ will be same

$\displaystyle\implies |p|=|q|=\frac{|p+q-a|}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2}} $

If $\displaystyle p,q>0,p=q=\frac{2p-a}{\sqrt2}\implies (2-\sqrt2)p=a\iff p=\frac a{2+\sqrt2}$

Now, $IC=|\sqrt{(p-a)^2+(q-a)^2}|=\sqrt2|p-a|$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think so ! Thank you ! +1

Comment: @Ewin, my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing how to get the answer you posted, but here's my try.

Take the triangle to have vertices $(\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}a}{2}, 0), (0, \frac{\sqrt{2}a}{2})$.

The centroid and the incenter will both lie on the $y$-axis by symmetry.

The centroid is the average of the vertices:  $(0, \frac{ \sqrt{2} a}{6})$.

By Heron's formula, the radius of the incircle is $$r = \frac{2K}{P} = a \left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right),$$

where $K = a^2/2$ is the area of the triangle and $P = (2+\sqrt{2})a$ is the perimeter.

So the distance between these is

$$\frac{3 - \sqrt{2}}{3}a.$$